# get sub categories of several categories with get_categories()

Tags: wordpress, categories

Is there a way to get all sub categories of several categories? something like:

```
get_categories( array( 'child_of'=>array(10,3,8) );
```

Comment: My dream is to know why people unvote me sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible, wordpress just accepts one integer in all it's functions that get categories children. You'll have to get their children separately:

```
$terms = array();
$taxonomy = 'category';
$parents = array(10, 3, 8);
foreach ($parents as $parent) {
    $terms = array_merge($terms, get_categories(array('child_of'=> $parent)));
}

foreach ($terms as $term) {
    // your code here
}
```

Hope it helps!