# How to exclude child categories from multiple parents in WP_Query?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach

I have some code

```
<?php
        $exclude_category = [10];

        $company_category_parents = get_categories( array('child_of' => 5) );
        foreach ($company_category_parents as $company_category_child) {
            array_push($exclude_category, $company_category_child->cat_ID);
        }

        $interviews_category_parents = get_categories( array('child_of' => 58) );
        foreach ($interviews_category_parents as $interviews_category_child) {
            array_push($exclude_category, $interviews_category_child->cat_ID);
        }

        $recent_news_main_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'category__not_in' =>  $exclude_category,
        ) );
```

Category with `id = 10` single category. Categories with `id = 5` and `id = 58` have children categories and they are actually parent categories id. As you can see in my code I'm making 2 foreach loops and I'm pushing data to array. It's quite good for now but it can be more than 2 categories with childrens in future. So my question is, is it any way to make it more usable with more than 2 ids? I want to type single category ID in one place and parent categories ID in second place and in final result I want to have one array with single ids and children categories ids. So when parent category with ID 5 have children categories with ids `1, 2, 3` my final array should have `10, 1, 2, 3` How can I do this?

Comment: _“is it any way to make it more usable with more than 2 ids?”_ - sure, just add one level of looping. Put the IDs into an array, loop over that, and inside that loop, do what you are currently doing for one of those categories, replacing the `array('child_of' => 5)` part with the current ID from the outer loop …

Comment: So, I just use solution from this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35825561/get-sub-categories-of-several-categories-with-get-categories/35842101 and it's working like it should. Thanks!